# Image is not stopping after reaching max width of the screen

Tags: javascript

My question is: how do I stop the image from moving to the left when it reaches the user's maximum screen width? I tried the below method by using JavaScript but it is not working. Also when the image reaches the user's maximum width, it should change the direction and return to where it was before.

```
<img src="plane.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" id="plane">

<script type="text/javascript">

  var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var plane = document.getElementById("plane");
  var leftpos = 0;


setInterval(function(){
  if (leftpos != width) {

    leftpos += 10;
    plane.style.marginLeft = leftpos + 'px' 
  }else {
    // change the direction
  }
      
  
}, 50) // run code every 50 milliseconds
;



</script>
```

Appreciate your time and Take care.

Comment: Use `<` instead? The `leftpos` may never match the page width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `marginLeft` and the `width` of the image plus 10 is less than `window.innerWidth`.

```js
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var plane = document.getElementById("plane");
var leftpos = 0;
var right = true;


var id = setInterval(function() {
  if (right && leftpos + plane.width + 10 <= width) {
    leftpos += 10;
  } else {
    right = false;
    leftpos -= 10;
    if (leftpos <= 0) clearInterval(id);
  }
  plane.style.marginLeft = leftpos + 'px';
}, 50);
```

```html
<img src="plane.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" id="plane">
```